# first and second words of a h1 tag edited using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I add a span selection on the first word of a h1 tag, and then a different span selection on the second word with jquery please?

For example, I would like to change:

```
<h1>This is a title</h1>
```

to

```
<h1><span class="firstWord">This </span><span class="secondWord">is </span> a title</h1>
```

Comment: Do you need only two spans? or each word inside a h1 tag inside a separate span?

Answer (score 2):

```
var words = $('h1').text().split(' '); // Note that split isn't jQuery, it's just javascript.
```

Now you have an array of words you can work with and emit back out with spans and such, e.g.:

```
words[0] = '<span class="firstWord">' + words[0] + '</span>';
var sentence = $('h1').text(words.split(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
var parts = $('h1').text().split(' ');
parts[0] = '<span class="firstWord">'+parts[0]+'</span>';
parts[1] = '<span class="secondWord">'+parts[1]+'</span>';
alert(parts.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var splitted = $("h1").text().split(" ");

if(splitted.length > 0) {
    $("h1").html('').append("<span class='firstWord'>" + splitted[0] + "<span> ");
    if(splitted.length > 1) {
        $("h1").append("<span class='secondWord'>" + splitted[1] + "<span> ");
        for(var i=2;i<splitted.length;i++) {
            $("h1").append(splitted[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

or see the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5679R/)

Answer (score 0):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Jeuu3/

```
$('h1').html($('h1').html().replace(/^(\w+) (\w+)/, '<span class="firstWord">$1</span> <span class="secondWord">$2</span>'));
```

---

That said, it would be better to use something more generalized, such as [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/).

It's as simple as:

```
$('h1').lettering('words');
```

Then, you can add CSS for `.word1` and `.word2`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Jeuu3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this is only safe if there's no HTML in the `<h1>` tag (which is why `.text()` is used to get the initial value). I don't think it's really possible with HTML in the `<h1>` tag.

```
var $h1 = $('h1');
h1_words = $h1.text().split(' ');
if (h1_words.length >= 2) {
    h1_words[0] = '<span class="firstWord">'+h1_words[0]+'</span>';
    h1_words[1] = '<span class="secondWord">'+h1_words[1]+'</span>';
}
$h1.html(h1_words.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = $('h1').text().trim()

var strArray = str.split(' ');

var temp;

for(var i=1;i<strArray.length;i++){
   temp += strArray[i]+" "
}

var result = '<span class='firstWord'>'+strArray[0]+'</span>'+" "+temp.trim()

$('h1').text(result)
```